# Redimensionar un array dinámico en c++

Tags: c++

El objetivo es modificar el tamaño del array dinámico, incrementandolo en 5 cada vez que se llame a la función  ***redimensionar()***. Hago uso de un array dinámico **auxiliar** donde guardo los valores que contiene el array principal(vectord), libero la memoria de ***vectord*** y la igualo a el auxiliar.

No obstante al introducir los nuevos valores da error. Creo que el error esta en

> vectord = aux

Con esta linea quizás no este aumentando el tamaño del array, aunque ese es el objetivo.

*Aclarar que no quiero usar la definición std:: vector*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

void redimensionar(int *vectord,int &longitud);

int main()
{
    int longitud;
    int cont = 0;
    cout << "Introduzca el tamaño del array: ";
    cin >> longitud;

    int *vectord = new int[longitud];

    for(int i = 0; i < longitud; i++) 
    {
        cout << "Valor de la posicion[" << i << "]:";
        cin >> vectord[i];
        cont++;
    }

    redimensionar(vectord,longitud);

    for(int i = cont; i < longitud ; i++) /*Introducimos valores a partir de la última posición */
    {
        cout << "Valor de la posicion[" << i << "]:";
        cin >> vectord[i];

        cout << vectord[i]; /* Error al mostrar el contenido */
    }
}

void redimensionar(int *vectord, int &longitud)/* Incrementamos en 5 el tamaño del array dinamico */
{
    longitud = longitud + 5;

    int *aux = new int[longitud];

    for(int i = 0; i < longitud - 5 ; i++)
    {
        aux[i] = vectord[i];
    }

    delete[] vectord;

    vectord = aux;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en que la función redimensionar recibe un puntero por valor, por tanto, si cambias el valor del puntero, ese cambio no se ve reflejado fuera de la función.
Si cambias:

```
void redimensionar(int *vectord, int &longitud)
```

por

```
void redimensionar(int *&vectord, int &longitud)
```

la función funcionará como tú esperas.

Tal y como tienes el código ahora, esto es lo que pasa: imagina que vectord vale: 0x1111111. Cuando llamas a la función redimensionar, estás copiando ese valor (0x1111111) a la variable vectord de dentro de la función, es decir, vectord, dentro de redimensionar vale 0x1111111. Ahora, dentro de redimensionar, liberas la memoria y actualizas vectord, y ahora vectord vale, por ejemplo, 0x2222222. Sin embargo, el valor de vectord de fuera de la función no ha sido actualizado, porque vectord dentro de redimensionar es una copia, no una referencia (o un puntero, en este caso necesitarías un puntero a puntero, int **vectord).

Espero que te haya ayudado, si tienes alguna duda o algo no te ha quedado claro no dudes en preguntar!

Comment: Antes de nada, muy bien explicado, muchas gracias. Todo ha quedado claro excepto esto último: (o un puntero, en este caso necesitarías un puntero a puntero, int **vectord).

Comment: Cuando quieres cambiar el valor de una variable dentro de una función y quieres que el cambio "se vea" fuera de la función, pasas un puntero (o una referencia), por ejemplo, en este caso, pasas vectord*, para poder cambiar el valor apuntado por vectord. Pero, cómo cambiar vectord para poder cambiarlo en la función y que el cambio se vea fuera? Una opción es pasarlo por referencia (que es la solución que he propuesto), pero también puedes pasar un puntero a vectord, es decir, tendrías que pasar un puntero a puntero: int **vectord.